# Logic for Form Validation for JS

Tags: javascript, html, forms, validation, logic

Assume I have two forms, firstName and lastName.

I have an alphanumericvalidation method which I tested individually.

```
   function alphaNumericValidation(Name)
   {
     if(/[^a-zA-Z0-9]/.test(firstName.value) || firstName.value == "") 
     {
       Name.style.border = "1px solid red";
       Name.focus();
       return false;
    }
    return true;
   }
```

now, I have a validation method which the code submits to:

```
 <td><input type="submit" name="smbt" id="smbt" value="Next" class="nextBtn" onclick="return validation();"/></td>
```

the validation method is written as

```
  function validation()
  {
    var firstName = document.getElementById("firstName");
    var lastName = document.getElementById("lastName");

    if (alphaNumericValidation(firstName))
    {
        if (alphaNumericValidation(lastName))
        {
            return true;
        }
   }
   else
            return false;
```

however the logic is wrong and it does not work as intended. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: It would be interesting to know in which way it does not work 'as intended'. Do you get any error messages? Do you use [Firebug](http://getfirebug.com/) or [Chrome DevTools](https://developers.google.com/chrome-developer-tools/)? Something like this should be quite easy to figure out with the help of those tools.

Comment: for example, if I put an invalid input for "lastName" it works as intended however, if I put an invalid input for "lastName" and a valid input for "firstName" it submits to the next page. I will check out devtools for now..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
function alphaNumericValidation(Name) {
  if(/[^a-zA-Z0-9]/.test(Name.value) || Name.value == "") {
    Name.style.border = "1px solid red";
    Name.focus();
    return false;
  }
  return true;
}
```

You are testing on `firstName` inside `alphaNumericValidation`, it should be `Name` there, as you are passing `firstName` (or `lastName`) as the `Name` parameter to `alphaNumericValidation`.

**Edit**

Your `validation()` function does not return anything if only `firstName` is valid and `lastName` is not valid.

```
function validation() {
  var firstName = document.getElementById("firstName");
  var lastName = document.getElementById("lastName");

  if (alphaNumericValidation(firstName)) {
    if (alphaNumericValidation(lastName)) {
      return true;
    }
  // <-- When it gets to here, nothing is returned.. you could add `return false;` here to fix it.
  }
  else
    return false;
```

Try this instead:

```
if (alphaNumericValidation(firstName) && alphaNumericValidation(lastName)) {
  return true;
}
else
  return false;
```

**Edit 2**

You could just keep putting if statements inside if statements, that would work just fine as long as you make sure the function always returns something.

In your case I would probably write something like this:

```
function validation() {

  var firstName = document.getElementById("firstName");
  var lastName = document.getElementById("lastName");

  var valid = true;

  valid = valid ? alphaNumericValidation(firstName) : false;
  valid = valid ? alphaNumericValidation(lastName) : false;

  return valid;

}
```

This will keep running your validations until one of them returns `false`, then it will skip the ones after that and `validation()` will return `false`.

Comment: oh sorry, I fixed this error already. The problem I have is it will border correctly, but it will submit even though the form should return false and fail.

Comment: I thought I tried this as my first attempt as it was most logical and it failed..but I think that was when my alphavalidation function was broken.. thank you..

one more question would be, if I wanted to add more validations, would I have to keep using AND for everything or is there a more simple way to do this?